# My HTML editors are ignoring any value I set and are always taking their values from the request data. Why?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a situation in which there's an HTTP GET parameter with name "Date" and that makes impossible for me to create a TextBox which name is "Date" and setting the value I want on it.

In my View, if I write:

```
@Html.TextBox("Date", "99/99/9999")
```

The TextBox will be rendered not with the value `99/99/9999` but with the value that is coming from the request, let's say: `02/07/2012`. The same happens if I use `EditorFor` passing a value from the view-model (that I actively set to a value different from `02/07/2012`)

I cant override the request data no matter what.

What should I do?

**EDIT**

As Darin Dimitrov wisely explained, whenever you want to modify a value coming from the request in order to display it in the View, you have to remove it from `ModelState`.

This is specially useful when dealing with DateTime in GET requests. ASP.NET MVC Model binding forces the date to be in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` in GET requests. But when you want to display it to the user, you may want to reformat it to `dd/MM/yyyy` possibly using the `DisplayFormatAttribute`. However that is not possible unless you remove the date from ModelState first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I do?

Remove it from the ModelState in your POST controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Date");
    return View(model);
}
```

Obviously you don't won't to work with weakly typed helpers:

```
@Html.TextBox("Date", "99/99/9999")
```

You want to work with strongly typed models and editor templates:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
```

And in your POST controller action you will set the required date:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Date");
    model.Date = "99/99/9999";
    return View(model);
}
```

I have explicitly used string as the Date property here which is probably wrong, I was just stumped with the validity of the 99/99/9999 string as a date. But obviously the same applies for dates as well.

The reason for this is that HTML helpers first look at the ModelState when binding their values and after that in the model. So even if you modify the value in the model, if you have a different value in the ModelState (which often happens in POST actions) it will be the value from the ModelState that will get used. This is by design.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question stating that's actually a GET value. This may change your response. I understand your point and I'm checking it now.

Comment: @AndréPena, no, same applies with GET requests. If you have a query string parameter called `Date` and your GET controller action takes a view model with a property called Date as parameter, this value will be stored in the ModelState. So if you need to modify it in your action, you need to remove it from the ModelState as shown in my answer. If you are saying that the helper doesn't take into account the value you are passing to it, this means that you have a different value in the modelstate that you need to remove first.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your effort. I'm checking your solution and I'll come back to you in minutes

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I edited the question adding some clarification for future people facing the same problem I did